# Mockito Spring Camel @Autowire fail

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel, mockito

I'm trying to unit test a camel route.  The route under test extends a custom abstract RouteBuilder (I know about favouring composition over inheritance - this is maintenance code).  I've set up my test as @Roman Vottner did [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48060373/mock-apache-camel-out-location-in-junit-testing/48174587?noredirect=1#comment89285503_48174587).  Everything works (is initialized) until I hit the first abstract class up the hierarchy.  It has an @Autowired class which wasn't initialized (is null) even though it was mocked and @Autowired when the test started.  Any ideas on how to solve my injection problem?

```
@RunWith(CamelSpringRunner.class)
@BootstrapWith(CamelTestContextBootstrapper.class)
@ContextConfiguration(loader = AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class, classes = {FooRouteTest.ContextConfig.class})
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.AFTER_CLASS)
public class FooRouteTest {

  @Configuration
  @PropertySource({"classpath:some.properties", "classpath:environment.properties"})
  public static class ContextConfig extends CamelConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public UserServices userServices() {
      return mock(UserServices.class);
    } //and many more of the like
  }

  @Autowired
  private UserServices userServices; //and all the others too

  @Test
  public void testAfoo() throws Exception {
//....
    template.setDefaultEndpointUri("direct://getTheData");
    template.sendBody(mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(jsonNode));
//...
  }
}
```

in the abstract super class while debugging:

```
@Autowired
public ClientServices clientServices;
//...
String clientNumber=clientServices.getLoggedInNumber();  //clientServices is null and not mocked!
//...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by explicitly declaring FooRoute as a bean:

```
@Bean
public FooRoute fooRoute(){
  return new FooRoute();
}

@Override
public List<RouteBuilder> routes() {
  final List<RouteBuilder> routes = new ArrayList<>();
  routes.add(fooRoute());
  return routes;
}
```

[image]